# Why don't nested constructor calls compile?

Tags: c++

Why does the following not compile:

```
typedef int Table;

class FullObjId 
{
public:
    explicit FullObjId( const Table* i ) {}
};

class TableInfo 
{
public:
    TableInfo( const FullObjId& o ) {}
    bool isValid() { return true; }
};

void dataSourceForHist( const Table& table )
{
   // The next line gives an error
   TableInfo tableInfo( FullObjId( &table ) );
   // Unless it's written like this:
   //TableInfo tableInfo( ( FullObjId( &table ) ) );

   if (!tableInfo.isValid())
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

I have tried with the Intel Compiler 12.1 for Linux, and using http://gcc.godbolt.org/ with g++ 4.8, icc 13.0, clang 3.4.1.
All the compilers I have tried give an error along the lines of:

```
error: request for member ‘isValid’ in ‘tableInfo’, which is of non-class type ‘TableInfo(FullObjId&)’
```

Comment: Does `TableInfo tableInfo(static_cast<FullObjId>(&table));` work ?

Comment: Because that line is declaring `tableInfo` as a *function* taking a parameter named `table` with type `FullObjId&` and returning `TableInfo`. There's a whole bunch of similar questions on SO, search for *most vexing parse*. This is valid, btw, and the error is coming from the expression in the `if` statement that follows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (also called *most vexing parse*) relies on the fact that:

```
TableInfo tableInfo( FullObjId( &table ) );
```

[is interpreted as a function](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbed21fdb5e31ffd) declaration.

Assuming you are using C++11, you should use:

```
TableInfo tableInfo{ FullObjId( &table ) };
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9224050a5f72b852)

instead.

Alternatively you can add extra parenthesis (works on C++03):

```
TableInfo tableInfo( (FullObjId( &table )) );
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bbf5760b53c36cd)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> TableInfo tableInfo( FullObjId( &table ) );
> ```

Declares `tableInfo` to be a function which takes a reference to `FullObjId` (the name of the parameter is `table`) and returns `TableInfo`. This is the so-called [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Workaround with C++11:

```
TableInfo tableInfo( FullObjId{&table} );
```